# Spring repository pagerequest orderby string combination of multiple columns

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve objects from a spring data repository by passing a `PageRequest` to the `findAll()` method. My problem is that i want to have the objects sorted by a combined string of multiple columns.

Lets say i have an object called Customer with the fields fname, sname. And these are our entries:

```
fname    |    sname    |
------------------------    
Peter    |    Parker   |
Bruce    |    Wayne    |
         |   Magneto   |             
         |  Wolverine  |
```

As a sorted output i want the order to be:

1. Bruce Wayne
2. Magneto
3. Peter Parker
4. Wolverine

I tried this:

```
List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "fname"));
orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "sname"));
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(orders));

Page<Customer> customers = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
```

But the order i got was:

1. Magneto
2. Wolverine
3. Bruce Wayne
4. Peter Parker

because fname of Magneto and Wolverine are empty, and therby before B for Bruce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sbjavateam is correct in that you can't do it without providing a custom query. But I think the query you want to use is

```
select c from Customer c order by CONCAT (c,firstName, ' ', c.lastName)
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach is the easiest i think. As long as you remove the space ('  ') .

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it with spring data order as you should work with null values and sorting by 2 columns, but you can sort it with @Query spring data

```
@Query("select c from Customer c order by ISNULL(c.firstName ,c.lastName) asc ,c.lastName")
Page<Customer> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```